# Turning JSON to a Data Frame in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to transform JSON into a Dataframe. I'm trying to get daily information about stocks and turning it into a dataframe so I can transform it into a graph in order to make analysis.

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "^BVSP",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-04-03",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-04-03": {
            "1. open": "72241.0000",
            "2. high": "72241.0000",
            "3. low": "67802.0000",
            "4. close": "69538.0000",
            "5. volume": "10411300"
        },
        "2020-04-02": {
            "1. open": "70969.0000",
            "2. high": "73861.0000",
            "3. low": "70957.0000",
            "4. close": "72253.0000",
            "5. volume": "10540200"
        },
        "2020-04-01": {
            "1. open": "73011.0000",
            "2. high": "73011.0000",
            "3. low": "69569.0000",
            "4. close": "70967.0000",
            "5. volume": "10093500"
        }
```

This is a portion of the JSON file I'm getting from the API. Currently my code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

response_ibov = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=^BVSP&apikey=XXX")
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=^BVSP&apikey=XXX"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'open': 'close'})
data_ibov = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```

I wanted to organize this like
Column Headers = Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
Rows = Dates

Does anyone know how to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['Time Series (Daily)'],orient='index')` where `d` is your json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposed answer using pandas:

```
#Your code
response_ibov = requests.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query? 
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=^BVSP&apikey=XXX")
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query? 
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=^BVSP&apikey=XXX"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'open': 'close'})

# Use pandas from_dict function to get Time Series only
# orient = index to get correct form of dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r.json()["Time Series (Daily)"],orient='index')

# In case you want to change column names
#df.columns = ['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']

print(df)

            1. open      2. high      3. low       4. close      5. volume
2019-11-06  108719.0000  109633.0000  107446.0000  108336.0000   5505500
2019-11-07  108360.0000  109672.0000  108360.0000  109581.0000   6075600
2019-11-08  109572.0000  109572.0000  107127.0000  107629.0000   5419600
2019-11-11  107622.0000  108263.0000  106814.0000  108215.0000   3928900
2019-11-12  108368.0000  108368.0000  106232.0000  106785.0000   5219300
```